# how to calculate the bounding box of an axis aligned ellipse for given centerpoint and axis aligned intersection line at distance h from a bound

Tags: math, winapi

How to calculate the bounding box of an axis aligned ellipse for given centerpoint cx,cy and an axis aligned intersection line with endpoints x1y1 and x2y2 at distance h from a bound ?

My purpose is to draw part of an ellipse, using the win32 Chord function.
[Chord function (wingdi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-chord)

This drawing shows a chord at the bottom side of an ellips bounding rectangle, giving y3=y1+h.

[image]

Comment: You can't, because your image isn't complete yet: with _just_ the center (cx,cy) and the two points p1 and p2, there are an infinite number of axis-aligned ellipses possible (just take your image and draw a second ellipse that is less wide, but much taller). You need at least one more coordinate to fully constrain the ellipse.

Comment: Indeed. I modified the question and specified the missing coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an axis-aligned ellipse means we just need to find the values for our major and minor radii, after which we know our bounding box, since that'll be a box with width `2b`, height `2a`, and center `(h,k)` (using the letters that maths uses when describing ellipses). And of course, once we have those, we can trivially derive the corner points if we need minx/miny/maxx/maxy coordinates instead.

So, the formula for an ellipse centered at (h, k) is:

```
 (x-h)²    (y-k)²
─────── + ─────── = 1
   a²        b²
```

and from your diagram we know `h = cx`, `k = cy`, `a = y3 - h`, and we know not just one, but three points on our ellipse. That leaves us needing to find one unknown, which is pretty easy: using `x = x1 - cx` and `y = y1 - cy`, we [solve for `b`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve+%5C%2840%29Divide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Ba%2C2%5D%5D+%2B+Divide%5BPower%5By%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Bb%2C2%5D%5D+%5C%2841%29+%3D+1+for+b) and get

```
          ay
b = ± ─̲─̲─̲─̲─̲─̲─̲─̲─̲──
      ⎷│a² - x²│
```

And we're done. We have all the values we need to build that AAB box now.